# How to make VS put all output files into the same folder if project configuration names differ?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

We have a solution configuration called "Debug".

The solution contains multiple projects which have various configuration names, like "Debug", "unit test", "test", etc.

The problem is that when we build the solution, the outputs are scattered in folders matching the project configuration name. So they are put into the "debug", "unit test", "test" etc folders.

The reason of the naming is because there are other solution files and configurations that build projects using a different constellation of configurations.

I would like to set the output folder so it matches the **solution configuration**'s name, not the **project configuration**'s name. So all stuff should be put into the "Debug" folder. Is it possible to do that somehow?

I basically look for something like the `$(ConfigurationName)` envvar but for the solution config name not for the project config name.

UPDATE:

These are C++ projects. Since it seems Visual Studio behaves differently for different kinds of projects.

Answer (score 1):

I am in VS2013, but I would imagine this is not a new feature.

Go to your Solution Properties, select Build on the left, and at the bottom you can specify the Output path.  You can specify a relative path in this field and put the output wherever you desire.

Comment: VS2008 doesn't seem to have that Build tab on the properties page.

Comment: Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165410(v=vs.90).aspx). Or this might work too. [How to: Build to a Common Output Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165411(v=vs.90).aspx)